# Use multiple message brokers with celery and django

Tags: python, django, celery, celery-task

I am using celery with django.
I'm have two celery apps running on the same server but using different message brokers.
One is using redis another is using django-orm.
The app using the redis backend is configured to receive tasks from only a signgle queue.
The other app is configured to handle all other queue.
Now the problem is if i enable the app with the redis bankend the other app stops receiving any tasks at all from the orm backend.

How can i accomplish this?

This is what i have done.
In settings.py

```
BROKER_URL = 'django://'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'

CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_ROUTES = {'dbmlib.imagecache.tasks.gen_cache_s3': {'queue': 'imagecache'}}
```

The apps.

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'settings')

app = Celery('celeryapp')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


img_caching_app = Celery('img_caching',broker='redis://10.0.0.106:6379/14')

img_caching_app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
img_caching_app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

I'm running the workers as such:

```
celery -A cms_celery.img_caching_app worker -Q imagecache -l info
celery -A cms_celery.celery_app worker -l info
```

Comment: hey, did you managed to do that? I need to do the same trick